# Use python docxcompose to merger document, how to deal with the different header?

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I have many documents, and these documents only have one page, but it have different header, I use python `docxcompose` to merger these documents ,but this operation will change all the header to the first document or the master document, is there any way to avoid this? I just want these documents have different header.

I add the `is_linked_to_previous=False` while I merge these documents, but it did not work

This is the code I an using:

```
def megerDocToOne(self, seperatepath, megerpathAndFileName):

        original_docx_path = seperatepath
        new_docx_path= megerpathAndFileName

        all_word=os.listdir(original_docx_path)
        all_file_path=[]
        for file_name in all_word:
            all_file_path.append(original_docx_path+file_name)
        master=Document(all_file_path[0])

        middle_new_docx=Composer(master)
        num=0
        for word in all_file_path:
            word_document=Document(word)
            word_document.add_section(WD_SECTION_START.NEW_PAGE)
            header = word_document.sections[0].header
            header.is_linked_to_previous = False

            if num!=0:
                middle_new_docx.append(word_document,True)
            num=num+1
        middle_new_docx.save(new_docx_path)
```